# Choice of public key and private key in RSA

Tags: totient-function

I am trying to dig as deep as I can into the RSA algorithm and trying to wrap my head around why the public key and it’s mod inverse have to be less than $\varphi(n)$. $\varphi(n)$ is the number of numbers that are co prime with $n$ right ? And not the actual number that is coprime. How is picking numbers less than $\varphi(n)$ helping ?

Comment: Because $$(a^{\phi (n)} \bmod n)=1\,,\quad \gcd(a,n)=1$$ see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Generalizations).

Comment: **$\varphi(n)$ is the number of numbers that are co prime with $n$ right ?**  No, there are infinitely many numbers which are coprime to any given number $n$. :)

Comment: Ok, then it’s the number of numbers that are coprime with n and less than n